# Get activity instance of MyFirebaseInstanceIDService

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` which extended to `FirebaseInstanceIdService`. I want to use activity instance in my `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` in Firebase Cloud Messenging. Is it possible ? If yes then how ? Here is some snippet for reference.

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

    private Activity mActivity = null;

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.i(TAG, "onTokenRefresh: RefreshedToken >> " + refreshedToken);

        //I  want to do some operation here and want to use Activity instance.

        callMethod(mActivity);
    }
}
```

Comment: what activity instance?

Comment: I want to call one method which needs activity instance. Question is updated @TimCastelijns

Comment: @Kuls show code of `FirebaseInstanceIdService`

Comment: @maveň That is library class of com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1

Comment: Why not call `callMethod(this)`?

Comment: do you have class named `MyFirebaseMessagingService` in that there is a method named `onMessageReceived` write code there to for Activity.

Comment: why do you need an activity instance?

Comment: @KNeerajLal I have tried and it ain't work

Comment: @TimCastelijns As i told you i want to call one method which needs an activity instance. Please read my question again

Comment: @Kuls now you have changed your question completely, Better to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @maveň I believed you got confuse of my question. So i have changed my way to explain that.

Comment: why does the method need an activity specifically? Maybe just a context is enough?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get only context by using **getApplicationContext**. You can not referrence activity.

Comment: This is NOT what I want. Thanks!